# Apache cordova example API is not working if its not in the index.html

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, indexing

I have been having a problem with Apache cordova, if I copy the source code to get a photo from the API (at bottom is the URL) in my index.html it works perfect, but if I copy the same source code in a second.html that is reachable from the index.html clicking a button that is a link, then in this case it doesn't work.

It looks like I have to put all the functions in the index.html because the error I am getting in the last case is

```
Undefined reference error : function is not defined
source: file :///android_asset/www/index.html
```

So how can I solve this ? Is it impossible to use the API from cordova in another page different from the index ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: I am using jquery mobile and importing it in index.html (I've just seen that if it took it out then everything works! But i really need it so if you can tell me a solution i would really appreciate it)

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Error Is a directory (file:///#android\_asset/www/index.html)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535382/application-error-is-a-directory-file-android-asset-www-index-html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when using JQM and the camera plug in, my application wont work.
I found that the DeviceReady event was not fired.
That is the reason for

```
Undefined reference error : function is not defined
```

First of all:
instead of calling the second page using the href = "otherPage.html"
 I did this:

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
    <a id="btnCamera" href="#" class="ui-btn">Go to camera</a>
</div>
```

and then create a script to handle the click event of the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnCamera").bind("click", function(event) {
            window.location.assign("otherPage.html");
            });

</script>
```

this change made the second page to fire the DeviceReady event.

everything worked fine for me.