# cordova-android 3.4.1 not owrking with phonegap 2.9.1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

i am building my first android application using phonegap. i have phonegap 2.9.1 installed and i am using cordova 3.4.1.jar file. the cordova.jar file isn't working with the phonegap version and i am using eclipse juno for java developers. i used the eclipse to build android apps alone but i am also trying to use nit to build phonegap apps for android

When i run the application, all i get is

```
Temporary network error. file:///android_assets/www/index.html
```

where am i wrong here because i couldn't generate the cordova-android 2.9.1.jar for phonegap 2.9.1 thats why i am using the .jar file i am using?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535382/application-error-is-a-directory-file-android-asset-www-index-html

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it. i simply went to apache.org and downloaded cordova-master 2.9.1 and ran the necessary command on my windows cmd and voila, i got my jar file.

Thanks to all that contributed